# How to calculate fan-in and fan-out in Xavier initialization for neural networks?

Tags: initialization, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Variations I have found of the Xavier initialization for weights in a Neural Network all mention a **fan-in** and a **fan-out**; could you please tell how those two parameters are computed? Specifically for these two examples:

1) initializing the weights of a convolutional layer, with a filter of shape [5, 5, 3, 6] (width, height, input depth, output depth);

2) initializing the weights of a fully connected layer, with shape [400, 120] (i.e. mapping 400 input variables onto 120 output variables).

Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

This answer is inspired by Matthew Kleinsmith's [post](https://medium.com/impactai/cnns-from-different-viewpoints-fab7f52d159c) on CNN Visualizations on Medium.

Let's start by taking a dense layer as shown below that connects 4 neurons with 6 neurons. The dense layer has a shape of [4x6] (or [6x4] depending on how you implement matrix multiplication).

The neurons themselves are often referred to as layers. It's common to read the below architecture as having an input layer of 4 neurons and output layer of 6 neurons. **Do not get confused** by this terminology. There is only one layer here - the dense layer which transforms an input of 4 features to 6 features by multiplying it with a weight matrix. We want to calculate fan_in and fan_out for correct initialization of this weight matrix.

- fan_in is the number of inputs to a layer (4)
- fan_out is the number of outputs to a layer (6)

[image]

The above image was generated using this [wonderful tool](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/index.html) by Alexander Lenail.

```py
>>> from torch import nn
>>> linear = nn.Linear(4,6)
>>> print(nn.init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(linear.weight))
(4, 6)
```

Similarly, a Conv Layer can be visualized as a Dense(Linear) layer.

[image: the image] The Image

[image: the filter]  The Filter

[image: Output] Since the filter fits in the image four times, we have four results

Here’s how we applied the filter to each section of the image to yield each result

[image]

The equation view

[image]

The compact equation view

[image]

and now most importantly the neural network view where you can see each output is generated from 4 inputs and hence fan_in = 4.

[image: The compact equation view]

If the original image had been a 3-channel image, each output would be generated from 3*4 = 12 inputs and hence fan_in would be 12. Hence,

```py
receptive_field_size = kernel_height * kernel_width
fan_in = num_input_feature_maps * receptive_field_size
fan_out = num_output_feature_maps * receptive_field_size
```

```py
>>> from torch import nn
>>> conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1,out_channels=1,kernel_size=2)
>>> print(conv.weight.shape)
torch.Size([1, 1, 2, 2])

>>> print(nn.init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(conv.weight))
(4, 4)
```

You can read more about weight initialization in my [blog post](https://adityassrana.github.io/blog/theory/2020/08/26/Weight-Init.html)

EDIT: Earlier this answer used an illustration taken from a [post](https://medium.com/comet-ml/selecting-the-right-weight-initialization-for-your-deep-neural-network-780e20671b22) by Gideon Mendels, which might lead to some confusion since a dense layer connects neurons and does not have any neurons itself. This was fixed thanks to @fujiu.

Comment: beautiful illustration! Thank you :)

Comment: While the first illustration using the MLP would be great for understanding the underlying concepts, it unfortunately seems to be based on a misunderstanding of fan-out. Please see [this discussion](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/issues/520) for more details. In short, the fan-out in the MLP case is equal to the number of outputs, which is also equal to the number of neurons in the layer, as can be seen in the [Keras codebase](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/2c48a3b38b6b6139be2da501982fd2f61d7d48fe/keras/initializers/initializers_v2.py#L972).

Comment: Accordingly, the fan-in for the middle layer is indeed 4, but its fan-out is 6, not 4 as in the illustration. If the fan-out indeed depended on the subsequent layer as suggested by the illustration, how could one then calculate the fan-out to initialize the output layer?

Comment: Dear @fujiu, you're absolutely correct. I was too focused on explaining fan_in and fan_out for convolutional layers, I overlooked that the first diagram is indeed wrong. Thank you so much for the catch! I have fixed it.

Comment: nice illustration~I am wondering why fan_out= num_output_feature_maps * receptive_field_size but not fan_out= num_output_feature_maps. In im2col implementation, the output units in matrix multiplication should be num_output_feature_maps? Hence fan_out should be num_output_feature_maps?

Comment: @adityassrana Can you elaborate on  the formula for `fan_out`?  I fail to see why we multiply with `receptive_field_size`.

Comment: Wow. What a fundamentally different way to view layers--not as arrays of neurons, but as arrays of arrows connecting one bunch of neurons to another bunch. Definitely requires a cognitive reshift, but makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that the fan in and out of a convolutional layer are defined as:

```
fan_in = n_feature_maps_in * receptive_field_height * receptive_field_width
fan_out = n_feature_maps_out * receptive_field_height * receptive_field_width / max_pool_area
```

where `receptive_field_height` and `receptive_field_width` correspond to those of the conv layer under consideration and `max_pool_area` is the product of the height and width of the max pooling that follows the convolution layer.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Source: [deeplearning.net](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html)

Comment: So in case of convolution, fan_in becomes (kernel_width x kernel_height x in_depth) ? and fan_out becomes (kernel_width x kernel_height x out_depth)? The tensorflow code just sets them to "in" and "out". There's no comment in the code what these actually are. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.15/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L31-L57